# How to insert data in Redis using NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, express, redis

Helo guys i'm just new in nodejs and redis but i don't have any idea on inserting data in redis using nodejs/express. Can you please help me or provide me an example? Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/mranney/node_redis

Comment: https://npmjs.org/package/redis

Answer (score 2):

You can use the most popular (at least for now) client module: [redis](https://npmjs.org/package/redis)

**Example** (from documentation)

```
var redis = require("redis"),
    client = redis.createClient();

// if you'd like to select database 3, instead of 0 (default), call
// client.select(3, function() { /* ... */ });

client.on("error", function (err) {
    console.log("Error " + err);
});

client.set("string key", "string val", redis.print);
client.hset("hash key", "hashtest 1", "some value", redis.print);
client.hset(["hash key", "hashtest 2", "some other value"], redis.print);
client.hkeys("hash key", function (err, replies) {
    console.log(replies.length + " replies:");
    replies.forEach(function (reply, i) {
        console.log("    " + i + ": " + reply);
    });
    client.quit();
});
```

Comment: Sounds like you need to look into HTML forms and HTTP REST the html form will POST data to the Express server. The express server will register a route, within that route you will add the data to redis. `app.post("/route",req,res,next(){ // redis code here}`